# Cannot connect to raspberry Pi through windows 10 file explorer network

Tags: networking, pi-2, windows

I'm trying to use my Raspberry Pi to set up a print server.

I've been following [this:](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-print-server/), and I got to the point where I had to access the Pi on another computer.

When I went to do said step, I couldn't access it. 
[image: Error Message]

I can use the [Remote Desktop Application](https://i.gyazo.com/0768548f88758eb319a75d445af35937.png) to access the Pi through [xrdp](https://i.gyazo.com/faa20571cbb12029f49502d548c3fa78.png) : and , but trying to remote access with the [file explorer](https://i.gyazo.com/47a8efaf5bbc1d1bff67ebd6423e9173.png) gives me [this error](https://i.gyazo.com/f54b87b353cbf08a2a0e6903c47a4377.png).

My router is a Touchstone DG3270A by Arris. I'm running windows 10 with an 15-6500, a GTX 1060, and 8GB of RAM.

The Raspberry Pi is a Pi 2 Model B running Raspbian (basically a default install.) It has CUPS and SAMBA installed, and I could access CUPS's admin page and set up my printer to be recognized by the Pi.

Comment: Have you mapped drives properly?   Also, which file manager do you mean?  Windows, or Raspbian?  If Windows, then perhaps try it from the other side - file explorer on raspbian should be able to connect. 
 Can you `sudo ping ` the windows machine, and `ping` the Rpi from the Windows machine?

Comment: You did follow step 4 and enable access for anything other than localhost.

Comment: Sorry could you clarify what mapping drives means?

Comment: @SDsolar I pinged my computer from the pi using Putty and got this: https://i.gyazo.com/cb255801dcff10283f87daaf51bbe494.png

and from my computer to the pi: 
https://i.gyazo.com/1088a7eaf5658cb8f336022486d15979.png

Comment: @AndyAnderson im guessing you were talking about the step to use:

sudo cupsctl --remote-any
sudo /etc/init.d/cups restart

i did that before, but I tried it again to be safe but now the Pi isn't showing up in the network screen

https://i.gyazo.com/5ebee8e98a55c318ccdfc53fa15ffa12.png

Comment: have you tried "accessing" the pi using IP address in windows? ... i.e \\192.168.0.14\

Comment: @JaromandaX how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Ok, really? Your first "image of an error" says "\\CBBA can't be found" ... I *assumed* you're trying to access the raspberry pi using the host name *CBBA* ... so ... instead of *CBBA*, use *192.168.0.14*

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah, I'm asking how to do that. Because I dont see any prompts that let me do that.

Comment: How did you get the error you posted a picture of? this is the problem with statements like "When I went to do said step" - which step? what did you do?

Comment: is it **Adding a Raspberry Pi Print Server to Windows** ?

Comment: @JarmandaX yeah im really stupid sorry. I tried directly connecting to the ip of the rpi, and it's giving me the same error. https://i.gyazo.com/3fbfe43734781117f2c6f5906e8d4bf8.png

Comment: Use your web browser to the iP for configuring CUPS. http://192.168.0.14